# Каким образом с этой страницы спарсить комментарии?

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

У меня слабые познания во фронтенде, но подозреваю, что комментарии подгружаются с помощью ajax или чего-то подобного.
Для парсинга страниц я использую python+beautifulsoup, и bs не видит подгруженный блок с комментариями, работая со страницей. 
Покопалась в исходном коде, но не смогла сообразить, что именно триггерит "comments-list-block" заполниться.

UPD: Спасибо первому комментатору, обнаружила, что ссылка не прикрепилась. Речь идет об этой странице: https://www.sports.ru/football/1063288512.html

Comment: Если вы о конкретно этой странице, то у SO есть удобный API - не нужно ничего парсить

Comment: Там внутри делается запрос на "https://www.sports.ru/api/comment/get/message.json" - просто "угадайте" (или лучше спросите у разработчиков) параметры и будет все очень удобно.

Comment: [тыц](https://www.sports.ru/api/comment/get/message.json?order_type=top10&message_id=1063288512&message_class=Sports%3A%3ANews&limit=10&from_id=undefined&new_time=1&style=newjs&page=1)